# Error when I trying to get API return value using json

Tags: javascript, json, async-await

I have some problems with my code. I am using the open weather API to create this application. I can easily get the values in the weather.js file and moving to UI. Only it has some values that responds with error in the console. Follows code and errors.

File weather.js

```
class Weather {
  constructor(city, state) {
    this.apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
  }

  // Fetch weather from API
  async getWeather() {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.city},${this.state}&APPID=${this.apiKey}`
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();

    return responseData;
  }

  // Change weather location
  changeLocation(city) {
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

File ui.js

```
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.location = document.getElementById("w-location");
    this.desc = document.getElementById("w-desc");
    this.string = document.getElementById("w-string");
    this.details = document.getElementById("w-details");
    this.icon = document.getElementById("w-icon");
    this.humidity = document.getElementById("w-humidity");
    this.feelsLike = document.getElementById("w-feels-like");
    this.dewpoint = document.getElementById("w-dewpoint");
    this.wind = document.getElementById("w-wind");
  }

  paint() {
    this.location.textContent = weather.name;
    this.desc.textContent = weather.weather[0].description;
  }
}
```

File app.js

```
// Init Weather Class
const weather = new Weather("rio de janeiro");

const ui = new UI();

// Get weather on DOM load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getWeather);

//weather.changeLocation("los angeles");

function getWeather() {
  weather
    .getWeather()
    .then(results => {
      ui.paint();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

> Console Error:
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> at UI.paint (ui.js:16)
>
> at app.js:15

In case if I make a console.log call in the weather.js file by the description property, it answers me correctly, but when I call in ui.js it gives this error.

And this is not just with this property, but with others as well, I tried to call the country property and says it is not set. How to solve? Can someone help me?

Comment: It seems likely the `weather.name;` and etc in `paint()` are referring to a `const weather = new Weather("rio de janeiro");` at the top of that file that was not in the snippet, is that correct? You need to pass the results from `getWeather()` to `ui.paint()`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd pass the results of the api call as a param to the `paint` method, since the `Weather` class doesn't have a `weather` property:

```
  paint(data) {
    this.location.textContent = data.name;
    this.desc.textContent = data.weather[0].description;
  }


function getWeather() {
  weather
    .getWeather()
    .then(results => {
      ui.paint(results);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Also make sure your api response actually has a `weather` prop, which is an array.

Comment: You can add this object to the question, but with this format the answer should work for you.

Comment: Hi Clarity,

I like to access the description inside weather Array

Comment: Actually I am unable to access any value that is within a subobject. For example: I have the weather object that contains everything, inside it there is the sys object, which has the properties country, id, etc ... I can't access the country for example.

Comment: I found out what was wrong, the first error was in the app.js file, when I called the ui.paint function I didn't pass the results and my second error was in the ui.js file when I create paint and don't pass the values either.

Answer (score 0):

Follows corrected code:

app.js

```
// Init Weather Class
const weather = new Weather("rio de janeiro");

const ui = new UI();

// Get weather on DOM load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getWeather);

//weather.changeLocation("los angeles");

function getWeather() {
  weather
    .getWeather()
    .then(results => {
      ui.paint(results);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

weather.js

```
class Weather {
  constructor(city, state) {
    this.apiKey = "17df2a26f3c8c6032f3eacdbbf3a8e25";
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
  }

  // Fetch weather from API
  async getWeather() {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.city},${this.state}&APPID=${this.apiKey}`
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();

    console.log(responseData);

    return responseData;
  }

  // Change weather location
  changeLocation(city) {
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

ui.js

```
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.location = document.getElementById("w-location");
    this.desc = document.getElementById("w-desc");
    this.string = document.getElementById("w-string");
    this.details = document.getElementById("w-details");
    this.icon = document.getElementById("w-icon");
    this.humidity = document.getElementById("w-humidity");
    this.feelsLike = document.getElementById("w-feels-like");
    this.dewpoint = document.getElementById("w-dewpoint");
    this.wind = document.getElementById("w-wind");
  }

  paint(weather) {
    this.location.textContent = weather.name;
    this.desc.textContent = weather.weather[0].description;
  }
}
```